# View with sequence in QGIS 2.4

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

In postgres, I created a view with a sequence nextval() to have an unique id (called vid).
I tried to vizualise this view in QGIS but it failed. It seems that nexval() causes some issue according to a message :

> "error : can't execute nextval() in a read only transaction"

How this issue can be solved please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get a unique integer field for QGIS to use as a key.  I've had luck using the [row_number](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html) window function for this. The basic syntax is:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () As vid, ...
```

That will give each row a sequential integer starting with 1.